# Why such iteration leads to fractal?

Tags: matrices, fractals

I saw a piece of codes like:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
t0 = AbsoluteTime[];
list = {{0, 0}};
last = {{0}, {0}};
GetNextPoint[pt_] := Module[{r,
   t1 = {{0.83, 0.03}, {-0.03, 0.86}}, p1 = {0, 1.5},
   t2 = {{0.2, -0.25}, {0.21, 0.23}}, p2 = {0, 1.5},
   t3 = {{-0.15, 0.27}, {0.25, 0.26}}, p3 = {0, 0.45},
   t4 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0.17}}, p4 = {0, 0}},
  r = Random[];
  If[r <= 0.85, t1.pt + p1, 
   If[r <= 0.91, t2.pt + p2, If[r <= 0.99, t3.pt + p3, t4.pt + p4]]]]
For[i = 0, i < 100000, i++, last = GetNextPoint[last];
 list = Append[list, First[Transpose[last]]];]
h = ListPlot[list, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.002], Red}, 
   Axes -> False];
range = First /@ Differences /@ (PlotRange /. Options[h]);
Show[h, AspectRatio -> Last@range/First@range]
Print[AbsoluteTime[] - t0]
```

which generates the following fractal picture after one or two minutes:
[image]

What is the mathematical principles behind the code? What kind of matrices can also lead to fractals? And how can I create similar fractals with different matrices?

**EDIT**

Someone suggested a more efficient code:

```
Clear["`*"];
t0 = AbsoluteTime[];
ifs[prob_, A_, init_, maxIter_] := 
  FoldList[#2.{#[[1]], #[[2]], 1} &, init, 
   RandomChoice[prob -> A, maxIter]];

init = {0., 0.};
prob = N@{85, 6, 8, 1};
A = N@{{{0.83, 0.03, 0}, {-0.03, 0.86, 1.5}}, {{0.2, -0.25, 0}, {0.21,
       0.23, 1.5}}, {{-0.15, 0.27, 0}, {0.25, 0.26, 0.45}}, {{0, 0, 
      0}, {0, 0.17, 0}}};
iter = 10^5;
pts = ifs[prob, A, init, iter];
Graphics[{PointSize[0.002], Green, Point[pts]}, Background -> Black]
Print[AbsoluteTime[] - t0]
```

Comment: It seems off topic, at least 2/3 of questions, maybe math.SE is better?

Comment: It's called the Lindenmayer system: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LindenmayerSystem.html

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnsley_fern, and the references therein.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the code is not particularly good.  I have a package that generates the image, with all 100000 points and colors, in well under half a second.

Comment: @Mark Are you going to post it?  If not I am closing this question as it isn't otherwise about *Mathematica*.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Not planning to - I think it should be closed.

Comment: I have updated the code. thanks